Распарсить лог файл в PowerShell через регулярные выражения
Есть log файл такого типа
02.11.2024 19:13:47.431  Connect socket [73664050] ("", "10.10.10.1")
02.11.2024 19:13:47.789  [159211164] TX 
02.11.2024 19:13:47.789  [159211164] RX 
02.11.2024 19:13:47.797  [159211164] TX 
02.11.2024 19:13:47.797  [159211164] RX
02.11.2024 19:13:48.274  Socket [73664050] info: (...э.A ...эADDRESS=71F2;71F2§.)
02.11.2024 19:13:48.274  Socket [73664050] device codes 71F2 (29170)
02.11.2024 19:15:14.257  [73664050] TX
02.11.2024 19:15:14.257  [73664050] RX 
02.11.2024 19:15:14.267  [73664050] TX 
02.11.2024 19:15:14.267  [73664050] RX
.....
02.11.2024 19:20:14.907  [159211164] TX 
02.11.2024 19:20:14.907  [159211164] RX 
02.11.2024 19:20:14.921  [159211164] TX 
02.11.2024 19:20:14.921  [159211164] RX 
02.11.2024 19:20:20.142  [159211164] RX 
02.11.2024 19:20:20.992  Disconnect socket [73664050] ("", "10.10.10.1")
02.11.2024 19:20:21.106  [159211164] RX 
02.11.2024 19:20:21.127  [159211164] RX
02.11.2024 19:20:21.396  [159211164] TX 
02.11.2024 19:20:21.396  [159211164] RX 
02.11.2024 19:20:21.405  [159211164] TX 
02.11.2024 19:20:21.405  [159211164] RX 06
02.11.2024 19:20:22.227  Connect socket [184509040] ("", "10.10.10.2")
02.11.2024 19:20:22.962  Socket [184509040] info: (...э.A ...эADDRESS=7192;7192.м)
02.11.2024 19:20:22.962  Socket [184509040] device codes 7192 (29074)

Необходимо получить ip адрес и код устройства в таком формате
Device_Code     ip
71F2 (29170)    10.10.10.1
7192 (29074)    10.10.10.2

Проблема заключается в том, внутри коннектов могут фигурировать дисконекты по другим устройствам. И разграничить их получается только по сокетам.
UDP
Попробовал создать регулярное выражение для выборки данных
Пример регулярного выражения
foreach($file in $filesed)
{
    $arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path $file -Encoding ansi
    $arrayFromFile -split '\n' | Select-String -Pattern $patern |
          ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                LineNanber = $_.LineNumber
                Cocket = $_.Matches.Groups[1]
                coments = $_.Matches.Groups[2]
                text = $_.Matches.Groups[3]
          }
        }      
}

Но вывод не тот чего я ожидал. Не могу исключить из поиска info

А в чём помогать? что ВЫ уже сделали? Где ваш код? что в нём КОНКРЕТНО не работает или работает не как ожидалось?

@Akina, В PowerShell могу считать файл без каких либо проблем. Проблема в написание регулярного выражения чтоб получить всю требуемую информацию. id устройства могу вот так получить (?device codes.{5}), но его ip в другой строке. Поэтому прошу помощи для того чтоб подали идею как сделать более правильно. Может сгруппировать по Socket

Ну если исходить из показанного... делайте по шагам. Сначала - выберите только строки, в которых есть слово socket. Затем выберите массив уникальных идентификаторов сессии, это которые в квадратных скобках. И затем заполняйте поля требуемых значений для каждого идентификатора. Это неоптимально, но понятно, прозрачно и достаточно быстро.

@Akina, создало пример, но что-то запутался

Возможно, что решить задачу с помощью только регулярных выражений не получится. Поэтому, нужно разбить решение на два этапа.
Сначала с помощью регулярок извлечь данные по отдельности:



Socket
Property
Value




73664050
IP
10.10.10.1


73664050
Device Codes
71F2 (29170)



А потом с помощью Group-Object объединить записи:
@(
    @{ Socket = "73664050"; Property = "Device Codes"; Value = "71F2 (29170)" }
    @{ Socket = "73664050"; Property = "IP"; Value = "10.10.10.1" }
    @{ Socket = "73664051"; Property = "IP"; Value = "10.10.10.2" }
    @{ Socket = "73664051"; Property = "Device Codes"; Value = "7192 (29074)" }
) | Group-Object -Property { $_.Socket } |
Select-Object Name,
@{Name="IP";Expression={($_.Group | Where-Object {  $_.Property -eq "IP" }).Value} },
@{Name="Device Codes";Expression={($_.Group | Where-Object {  $_.Property -eq "Device Codes" }).Value} }


В примере входным объектом для Group-Object является хэш-таблица. Для другого типа входного объекта обработка в Group-Object будет другая.

Возможны и другие решения, например:

Отфильтровать строки по "Connect socket" и "device codes" (порядок строк изменён для примера) и убрать время

Socket [73664050] device codes 71F2 (29170)
Connect socket [73664050] ("", "10.10.10.1")
Connect socket [184509040] ("", "10.10.10.2")
Socket [184509040] device codes 7192 (29074)


Заменить "Connect socket" на "Socket" и отсортировать

Socket [184509040] ("", "10.10.10.2")
Socket [184509040] device codes 7192 (29074)
Socket [73664050] ("", "10.10.10.1")
Socket [73664050] device codes 71F2 (29170)


Поиском и заменой (Regex) убрать лишнее

10.10.10.2")
Socket [184509040] device codes 7192 (29074)
10.10.10.1")
Socket [73664050] device codes 71F2 (29170)

-->

10.10.10.2 7192 (29074)
10.10.10.1 71F2 (29170)


Отредактировал вопрос. Немного не получается с регулярным выражением

А почему именно PowerShell?

Нужно искать либо ] ("", ", либо ] device codes . Залог успешного поиска - правильно выбранный критерий. Чем хорош этот? В обоих вариантах нужная информация находится непосредственно до искомого выражения и после него.

Получилась такая регулярка: ((\d+)] (\()"", "([0-9.]+))|((\d+)] (d)evice codes (.+)). Вторая группа - это признак типа данных: "(' - адрес IP; "d" - код устройства.

Да это хорошо работает, но почему то берутся еще дисконекты. Можно ли как то исключить их?

Ага, не увидел. (  Connect socket \[(\d+)] (\()"", "([0-9.]+))|((\d+)] (d)evice codes (.+))

Спасибо. Это действительно сработало.
